# canonical way of replacing group_by_at(vars(...)) by group_by(across(...))

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang

The current documentation of `group_by_at` notes, that the _at functions are superseded by using `across`.
However, `across` fails when I try
to restore the original grouping because it ignores the current grouping columns.

```
do_with_cut <- function(df) {
  groupVarsOrig <- group_vars(df)
  df %>% 
    group_by(.data$cut, .add = TRUE) %>% 
    summarise(price = mean(price)) %>% 
    #group_by_at(vars(groupVarsOrig)) # marked as superseded
    #group_by(across(groupVarsOrig)) # fails for missing column color
    ungroup() %>% group_by(across(groupVarsOrig))
}

ggplot2::diamonds %>% 
  group_by(color) %>% 
  do_with_cut()
```

In order to avoid these errors on re-grouping tibbles with unknown previous grouping
I have to `ungroup` before.

However, always preceding `group_by(across(...))` by `ungroup()` seems to me not a clear way of replacing the `group_by_at`. What is the now recommended way of re-grouping?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is after `summarise` it drops only the last group i.e `cut` so your data is already grouped by `color` hence it does not find the `color` column. See :

```
do_with_cut <- function(df) {
  groupVarsOrig <- group_vars(df)
  df %>% 
    group_by(.data$cut, .add = TRUE) %>% 
    summarise(price = mean(price)) 
}

ggplot2::diamonds %>% 
  group_by(color) %>% 
  do_with_cut() -> data

group_vars(data)
#[1] "color"
```

If you drop all the previous groupings using `ungroup` or `.groups` parameter then it works as expected.

```
do_with_cut <- function(df) {
  groupVarsOrig <- group_vars(df)
  df %>% 
    group_by(.data$cut, .add = TRUE) %>% 
    summarise(price = mean(price), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    group_by(across(groupVarsOrig))
}

ggplot2::diamonds %>% 
  group_by(color) %>% 
  do_with_cut() 

# A tibble: 35 x 3
# Groups:   color [7]
#   color cut       price
#   <ord> <ord>     <dbl>
# 1 D     Fair      4291.
# 2 D     Good      3405.
# 3 D     Very Good 3470.
# 4 D     Premium   3631.
# 5 D     Ideal     2629.
# 6 E     Fair      3682.
# 7 E     Good      3424.
# 8 E     Very Good 3215.
# 9 E     Premium   3539.
#10 E     Ideal     2598.
# … with 25 more rows
```